# Prime Number Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have an assignment and it says:

You have been provided a working program named Prime.
It has one input which is a single integer.
When the “Find Prime Number” button is pushed, the nth prime number is identified.

*For example:*

if 4 is entered and the button is clicked, the response is “The 4th prime number is 7” is displayed.  And if 9 is entered, the response is “The 9th prime number is 23” is displayed.

The program is 100% accurate, it correct locates the nth prime.
The problem comes in when you try to find larger prime number.

*For example:*

if 10000 is entered and the button is clicked, the response is “The 10000th prime number is 104729” is displayed.  This is the correct answer; however, it took over 48 seconds on my i7 computer to find the solution.  Imagine how long it would take to find the millionth prime number. Your task is analyze the problem to find a more efficient solution that would make the program more useful.  First you must understand how the code provided works.  There is an exercise at the end of this document.  You will use it to run the code by hand.  Once you understand how it works, analyze the problem of finding a prime number to make the program operate more efficiently.  The reason why the program is slow for large numbers is because I preform a lot of unnecessary calculations.  Not you must use your own code.  You cannot use any prebuilt prime number routines, functions, or libraries; doing so will result in a zero for the assignment.    Thinking about what really needs to be done is the way to solve this.

He says that the best way is to use arrays, but I don't know how to use arrays to solve this problem. He also says to keep division (mod) at a minimum as well as if statements.

Here is the code he provided for us:

```
Option Strict On
Public Class Form1


Private Sub PositionBox_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PositionBox.TextChanged
    If IsNumeric(PositionBox.Text) Then
        If Decimal.Parse(PositionBox.Text) >= 1 Then
            FindPrimeBtn.Enabled = True
        Else
            FindPrimeBtn.Enabled = False
        End If
    Else
        FindPrimeBtn.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub FindPrimeBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles FindPrimeBtn.Click
    Dim FinalPosition As Long
    Dim FinalPrime, Even As Long
    Dim Number As Long = 2
    Dim CurrentPosition As Long = 1

    Dim elapsed As System.TimeSpan

    Dim sw As Stopwatch = New Stopwatch()

    sw.Start() 'starts the clock
    Dim IsPrime As Boolean

    FinalPosition = Long.Parse(PositionBox.Text)

    Even = CurrentPosition Mod 2
    While (CurrentPosition > 2 And Even <> 0)
        IsPrime = True
    End While

    While (CurrentPosition <= FinalPosition)
        IsPrime = True

        For x = 2 To Number - 1
            If Number Mod x = 0 Then
                IsPrime = False
            End If
        Next

        If IsPrime Then
            FinalPrime = Number
            CurrentPosition += 1
        End If
        Number += 1
    End While

    elapsed = sw.Elapsed() 'captures the elapsed time it took to compute the result

    ResultLbl.Text = "The " + FinalPosition.ToString() + "th is " + FinalPrime.ToString()
    ElapsedTimeLbl.Text = "Elapsed time is " + elapsed.ToString()

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Interesting assignment.  I am not sure I would use arrays either, but one way to use them is this: as you are counting to the Nth prime number, you are testing smaller numbers for primality.  You can store them in an array and use them to perform more efficient primality tests on subsequent candidate prime numbers.

Comment: did you type the code in exactly as your instructor provided?  That first While loop looks out of place to me.

Comment: @JohnieKarr yes I did I did a copy and paste so it is the exact same code.

Comment: I really do not understand what he is doing in the code, but he will not provide help for his students.

Comment: you need to declare x, though, right?  And I think that first While loop is unnecessary, but it won't kill the performance for large numbers.

Comment: Concerning the array issue, create a list of prime { _Dim primelist As New List(Of Integer)()_ } and add all primes { _primelist.Add(Number)_ }, then loop on this list to assign x and test "Number mod x". For optimization, refer to [ sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

Comment: hmmm, well, I'm just sight reading the code, but it looks to me like the first while condition will never be true (CurrentPosition = 1, and thus is not > 2), and if it were, it would be an infinite loop...nothing to do with your question, just an observation.

Comment: Graffito is on the right track, but if your instructor insists you use an array, you will probably be docked for using a list.

Comment: Yeah, I can't use that because we haven't learned that in class yet and if we use anything we haven't learned in class he just gives us a 0. or if we use pre defined methods we receive 0's as well. we have learned about arrays but he hasn't gone into too much detail we just learned the basic declaration

Comment: @JohnieKarr how can i reduce the if statements and the mod then?

Comment: well, just like phoog said, you can create an array in the global scope and then whenever you find a prime number put it in the that array.  For subsequent checks, use the array for your starting point.  So, if you first enter 4, your array will contain 2, 3, 5, 7.  Then you enter 9, you already have the first 4, so start with 7 instead of 2.  The wikipedia link offered by graffito is very interesting also.

Comment: all you have to do is add `Exit For` in the for loop after `IsPrime=False`.  once you have determined that the current value is not a Prime, there is no need to keep testing ("unnecessary calculations").

Comment: that helped a lot @Plutonix

Comment: however it didn't make it as fast as he wants it but thank you

Comment: then change the loop to `For x = 2 To (Number \ 2)` to shave more time.

Comment: @Plutonix is there any way to get rid of the If statements?

Comment: According to this post on the SE Math site, all non-prime numbers are divisible by a prime number. So, instead of dividing by all the numbers below the current number, just divide by the prime numbers you have found up to that point that are less than half of the number you are checking. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/911655/why-are-all-non-prime-numbers-divisible-by-a-prime-number

Comment: because right now its computing in .24 sec but he wants at least .04 seconds for a B grade letter

Comment: If you can't use list, use you may define a counter and an array of arbitrary size that you will extend to an array twice bigger each time the counter exceeds array size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out
[this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_division) 
, specifically, where it says:
 *effort can be reduced by selecting only prime numbers as candidate factors. Furthermore, the trial factors need go no further than \scriptstyle\sqrt{n} because, if n is divisible by some number p, then n = p × q and if q were smaller than p, n would have earlier been detected as being divisible by q or a prime factor of q.*

I think he wants you to store the primes you find in an array and then iterate through the set of primes in the array instead of iterating through each or each odd number.

Not sure if he'll allow you to import system.math, where the square root function is, but that speeds it up.  I suppose you could ask...

Anyways, I'm not using the stored array of found prime numbers, and didn't like all his variable names, but if it helps, I was working with this:

```
Option Strict On
Imports System.Math

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub PositionBox_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PositionBox.TextChanged
        If IsNumeric(PositionBox.Text) Then
            If Decimal.Parse(PositionBox.Text) >= 1 Then
                FindPrimeBtn.Enabled = True
            Else
                FindPrimeBtn.Enabled = False
            End If
        Else
            FindPrimeBtn.Enabled = False
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub FindPrimeBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles FindPrimeBtn.Click
        Dim CurrentprimeSequence As Long = 1
        Dim FinalprimeSequence As Long
        Dim prime_possible As Double = 2
        Dim foundPrime As Double
        Dim test_div As Double
        'Dim Even As Long

        Dim elapsed As System.TimeSpan

        Dim sw As Stopwatch = New Stopwatch()

        sw.Start() 'starts the clock
        Dim IsPrime As Boolean

        FinalprimeSequence = Long.Parse(PositionBox.Text)

        'Even = CurrentprimeSequence Mod 2
        'While (CurrentprimeSequence > 2 And Even <> 0)
        '   IsPrime = True
        'End While
        FindPrimeBtn.Enabled = False

        While (CurrentprimeSequence <= FinalprimeSequence)
            IsPrime = True   ' until proven false

            test_div = 2
            Do While IsPrime And (test_div <= Sqrt(prime_possible))
                IsPrime = (prime_possible Mod test_div > 0)
                test_div = test_div + 1 - CDbl(test_div > 2)       ' skip odd numbers after 2
                'If test_div = 2 Then
                '   test_div = test_div + 1
                'Else
                '   test_div = test_div + 2
                'End If
            Loop

            'For test_div = 2 To Sqrt(prime_possible)         ' test if divisible by any number two to square root of candidate, skip even #s
            '   If prime_possible Mod test_div = 0 Then
            '       IsPrime = False
            '       Exit For       ' or change to while isprime and (test_div < prime_possible)
            '   End If
            'Next

            If IsPrime Then
                foundPrime = prime_possible
                If CurrentprimeSequence Mod 100000 = 0 Then
                    Debug.Print(CStr(CurrentprimeSequence) + " " + CStr(foundPrime) + " " + sw.Elapsed().ToString)
                End If
                CurrentprimeSequence += 1
            End If
            prime_possible += 1
        End While

        elapsed = sw.Elapsed() 'captures the elapsed time it took to compute the result

        ResultLbl.Text = "The " + FinalprimeSequence.ToString() + "th is " + foundPrime.ToString()
        ElapsedTimeLbl.Text = "Elapsed time is " + elapsed.ToString()
        FindPrimeBtn.Enabled = True
    End Sub
End Class
```

on my PC, it found the millionth prime in about 28 seconds, but you can't really compare performance across machines.

Comment: i cant import the math but i can just raise it to the half power. thanks